# Qt Signal при добавлении нового окна в приложении

Tags: c++, qt, сигналы-слоты

Существует ли возможность в Qt посредством SIGNAL отследить, если было добавлено новое QWindow окно? Необходимо, чтобы определённый объект следил за появлением данных окон.

Comment: Каких окон? Как они добавляются?

Comment: Необходимо отслеживать добавление нового QWindow. Сейчас я посредством потока это проверяю при помощи QApplication::allWindows(). Поэтому интересуюсь, если есть метод посредством SIGNAL это организовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готового сигнала нет. Но можно обрабатывать сообщения о создании виджетов. Для этого потребуется определить [фильтр сообщений](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) и подлючить его к объекту приложения QApplication.

Вот пример:

```
class WindowsMon: public QObject
{
   Q_OBJECT;
public:
   using QObject::QObject;

private:        
   bool eventFilter(QObject * target, QEvent * e) override;

public: signals:
    void windowCreated(QWindow * w);
};

bool WindowsMon::eventFilter(QObject * target, QEvent * e)
{
    if(e && QEvent::Create == e->type())
    {
        const auto window = qobject_cast<QWindow *>(target);
        if(window) // смогли пребразовать к QWindow
        {
            emit windowCreated(window);
        }
    }
    // на самом деле мы ничего не фильтруем, поэтому пробрасываем
    // сообщения дальше, тем более что висим на QApplication
    return QObject::eventFilter(target, e); 
}
```

Подключение:

```
auto winmon = new WindowsMon(QCoreApplication::instance());
QCoreApplication::instance()->installEventFilter(winmon);
```

Comment: Помог ваш вариант, но только вместо QApplication пришлось прописать QCoreApplication. Я пока новичок в qt и палил наугад, но повезло. Ещё раз спасибо!

Comment: @ГалицкийОлег Я вижу вы новенький, поэтому подскажу: коментарии тут для обсуждения если что-то не понятно. А вот эти "здрасте", "спасибо", "пожалуста" хоть и приятно, но не совсем приветсвуется так как создает лишний шум. Подразумевается что эти слова есть.